# Can't initialize object parser for model.Products, no acceptable constructors found

Tags: kotlin, anko

I follow [Stress-free SQLite with Anko](https://www.kotlindevelopment.com/anko-sqlite-database/) to learn Kotlin, so I created the class

```
data class Products(val id: Long, val name: String, val description: String, val price: Long, val image: String, val status: String, val type: String ) {

    companion object {
        val TABLE_NAME          = "gdbl_products"
        val COLUMN_ID           = "id"
        val COLUMN_NAME         = "name"
        val COLUMN_DESCRIPTION  = "description"
        val COLUMN_PRICE        = "price"
        val COLUMN_IMAGE        = "image"
        val COLUMN_STATUS       = "status"
        val COLUMN_TYPE         = "type"
    }
}
```

In Activity.kt I call:

```
var rowParser = classParser<Products>() => exception show: Can't initialize object parser for model.Products, no acceptable constructors found
```

Please tell me know why and how to fix it

Answer (score 1):

The [implementation](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/blob/master/anko/library/static/sqlite/src/ClassParser.kt) of this part of `classParser<T>()` looks like

```
val applicableConstructors = clazz.declaredConstructors.filter { ctr ->
    if (ctr.isVarArgs || !Modifier.isPublic(ctr.modifiers)) return@filter false
    val types = ctr.parameterTypes
    return@filter types != null && types.isNotEmpty() && types.all(::hasApplicableType)
}
```

So you have to find out, why your constructor doesn't actually match this requirements. It should not use *varArgs*, must be public and has to have applicable parameter types. At first sight, all looks fine, but you might be able to test which parts are wrong by removing single parameters until it works.

Additionally, and maybe unrelated, the example defines `val Book.COLUMN_ID = "id"` within the companion, while you only define `val COLUMN_ID = "id"`. The first one is an extension property, while yours is a property of the companion object.

Comment: I cannot define val Products.COLUMN_ID  = "id" it have exception, Android Studio suggest me "Convert extension property initializer to getter"

Comment: The last part was just a note. Maybe it's wrong in the example.